# Getting assets in Codeigniter giving error.

Tags: codeigniter

Im trying to get up an asset helper in Codeigniter. I have created the following file in application/helpers:

**asset_helper.php**

```
<?php

function asset_url(){
   return base_url().'assets/';
}

?>
```

I then inport this helper into my controller like so:

```
$this->load->helper('asset');
```

When I want to use an asses in my 'html' I do the following:

```
<link href="<?=asset_url()?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

My directory structure is:

```
application
system
assets
-- js
-- imgs
-- css
```

When my program is run I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/editor/application/controllers/pages.php on line 5
```

Where line 5 is where I try to call asset_url() like so: 
    /css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

Where am I going wrong, all my code seams to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function asset_url(){
   $CI =& get_instance();
   $ci->load->helper('url');
   return $ci->base_url().'assets/';
}
```

You have to get the instance of CI in order to load or use core functions on the helper

Answer (score 0):

Here is an asset helper for CodeIgniter. Also the asset helper having a feature to merge files into one file when the names are passed in array. So will help to reduce the number of HTTP requests in your website.

http://www.thephpcode.com/blog/view/css-and-javascript-asset-helper-for-codeigniter.html